# Remove Duplicate Dropdown Options with Sharing 2 Values

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a lot of javascript & jQuery that will allow you to remove duplicate select options based on the value, but i need to based it on 2 values.  Currently, my dropdown will produce a list of options formatted like:

```
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
```

I have scripts that will allow me to look at `manufacturer_chevy` and remove dups', but i need any duplicate option with `value="manufacturer_chevy"` & `data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy"` to be removed.

A couple that work based on 1 value:

```
$(".tag-base option").each(function() {
$(this).siblings("[value='"+ this.value+"']").remove();
});
```

and...

```
var found = [];
$(".tag-base option").each(function() {
if($.inArray(this.value, found) != -1) $(this).remove();
found.push(this.value);
});
```

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @Copper_Thompson, consider performance aspect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [Multiple Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/) like this:

```
$(".tag-base option").each(function() {
    var $t = $(this);
    $t.siblings("[value='"+ $t.val() +"'][data-id='" + $t.data("id") + "']").remove();
});
```

This will find and remove duplicates from your dropdown. A duplicate in this case is defined as "An option that shares the same value and data-id as another."

**EDIT:** As per your comment, you were looking to match on value and data-*id*, not data-*value*. I've edited my code to reflect this.

Comment: This is working, but still removes all.  I may have mis-styped.  Looking at example, <option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>, its not the data-value, but actually the data-id, since there may be trucks, vans, cars, etc.  Testing now and it looks like changing from value to id is going to work.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, no problem. I've edited my answer to use `data-id` instead, as you mentioned.

Comment: What is we modified this to only hide the elements?  I edited .remove() to .hide() with completely different results

Comment: You can't hide `<option>` elements. Putting `display: none;` on an `<option>` does nothing. [Example here.](https://jsfiddle.net/wooa9dzm/)

Answer (score 0):

In order to select all the options with the data-value attribute corresponding to a specified value you can use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

The code:

```js
$(".tag-base option").each(function(i, ele) {
  var val = ele.value;
  var eleToRemove = $(ele).siblings("[value='" + val + "']").filter(function(i, e) {
    var dVal = $(e).data('value');
    return dVal.toLowerCase() == val.toLocaleString();
  }).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select class="tag-base">
    <option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
    <option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

*Pure* *JavaScript* solution using `Document.querySelectorAll()`, `Node.getAttribute()` and `Node.removeChild()` methods:

**Pure Javascript approach is more than 10 times faster than JQuery's `$(el).siblings(...)` approach!**

```js
var attr_counts = {};
    
document.querySelectorAll('#truckList option').forEach(function(n){
    var hash = n.getAttribute('data-value') + n.getAttribute('value');
    (typeof this[hash] === 'undefined')? this[hash] = 1 : this[hash]++;
    if (this[hash] > 1) {
        n.parentNode.removeChild(n);
    }
}, attr_counts);
```

```html
<select id='truckList'>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Honda" value="manufacturer_honda">Honda</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Other" value="manufacturer_other">Other</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_GMC" value="manufacturer_gmc">GMC</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" value="manufacturer_chevy">Chevy</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_GMC" value="manufacturer_gmc">GMC</option>
<option data-id="truck" data-value="Manufacturer_Honda" value="manufacturer_honda">Honda</option>
</select>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t7cnt1xx/2/

Comment: This method relies on you supplying the duplicate values though, doesn't it? From OP's example snippets, I believe `Manufacturer_chevy` was an example, and it should remove all duplicates without requiring them to be previously specified.

Comment: @Santi, pay attention, the OP said *but i need any duplicate option with value="manufacturer_chevy" & data-value="Manufacturer_Chevy" to be removed.*

Comment: "Pay attention"...? You're a real charmer, aren't you. The context you've provided could easily be interpreted as an extension of his example. Both snippets he provided as "working codes" remove *all* duplicates, not specific ones.

Comment: @Santi, the OP will decide, don't bother. If he asked to "kill" all duplicates - I'll do it, but not when you asked

Comment: I should have specified, it is ALL duplicates, since there may be multiple